# Find a function that respect these 3 conditions

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, recurrence-relations, computational-complexity, nonlinear-optimization

I am developing a mobile app to help to memorize by heart and review a book and I don't know how to solve this math problem.
I have a function *f* which is a quadratic function representing the total number of memorized lines up to now (so *f '* is the number of new memorized lines for the day).
I'm looking for function *g* which is the number of lines to be revised per day knowing that

1. the book has "*l*" lines
2. 1. first, each new line memorized must be reviewed every day for "*a*" days
   2. then (after "*a*" days), the line must be reviewed once every "*b*" days.
3. "*b*" is a variable starting at "*c*" and incrementing by *1* at each revision until reaching "*d*".

I did calculus 1 & 2 and discrete math. Thanks

If the question is too difficult, I could define a, c and d and also give the function f

link to the same question on mathematics subreddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/mathematics/comments/ifbjbw/find_the_function_that_respect_these_3_conditions/

link to the same question on casual math subreddit (1 answer with algorithm): https://www.reddit.com/r/CasualMath/comments/ifbvvp/find_the_function_that_respect_these_3_conditions/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

EDIT : I used an algorithm to solve my problem

Comment: Probably should work with discrete functions

Answer (score 0):

Here's an attempt:$$g(t)=\sum_{n=1}^{a}f'(t-n)$$This formula only satisfies the first condition though. After this I get completely stuck. You would arrive at a system of difference equations with d members. Even with c and d given, this seems near futile.

But, since you're coding, you don't have to find a formula, there's a much simpler solution, but that's off topic for this website. If you want my advice on a coding solution to this problem, let me know in the comments, but I'm not sure how to solve your math problem.

Comment: Yes I would be happy with a code solution advice :)